# Would a multitouch capable PC allow me to do Android development simulating the touch UI without an Android device?

Tags: android

I recently purchased a Samsung Galaxy Tab as a reference implementation (phone and first gen Android tablet), of Android 2.x for app development.  I have noticed a slew of Android 3.0 slates being talked about at CES 2011 (Motorola XOOM, etc.).

If I had a multitouch PC with the Android SDK/Emulator on it, would this allow me to more closely approximate device simulation by allowing user input via the multitouch screen ?  Would it work via touch just like Windows 7 recognizes touch as mouse style input ?

Has anyone done this ?

Comment: This feels more like a SO question to me.

Comment: @Martijn - I had wondered about SO, but it was not a code specific question.  I have since posted there, just in case.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it takes 5 of us to feel the same way in order to close/move a question, and I'm in the minority for this one :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884362/how-to-test-multi-touch-in-android-emulator) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5977), the Android emulator does not support multitouch, although single-touch gestures should still be possible.